# questions about btree and index to database

Tags: mysql, database, indexing, b-tree

I read tons of articles about btree theorem about database..thing there is always bewildering.
assuming I have a table as described as follow:
table userinfo:
**(user_id as primary key, username as string, password as string)**
as described in some articles, the user_id is created as **index** for the table **userinfo**, I will get efficient preformance, if i **select** records by index of user_id..
but if i **select** by **username**, it's said it campares the lines one by one.....
I try this in ***MYSQL*** , it is not as slow as expected....
why?
how does **mysql** do with this selcetion??
thanx

Comment: It is not using an index, and indeed scans every row. But any decent database tries to optimize scanning as well. _"not as slow as expected"_ is not the same as _"as fast as it would be with an index"_, but selecting on a non-indexed column can be valid & fast _enough_.

Comment: @Wrikken: thanx for you instant reply..how does oracle solve this problem of selection of username, you know any table doesnot have only one column necessarily .

Comment: The width of columns is usually known, so scanning for a particular column at a particular byte offset is usually quite effective (and if the first byte there doesn't match discarding the row, etc.). Different databases may employ different tactics. If you really want to know, the source of `mysql` is freely available, so browse it that your leisure. Oracle probably employs a lot of the same tactics. I myself am quite content knowing how to use it as an enduser, no need here to know the nitty-gritty of implementation :)

Comment: What @Wrikken said, plus: for small tables, a table scan can be faster than indexed accesses.  For big enough tables (when you have millions of rows in the table), indexed access is usually more efficient, but it depends on the query.  Indexed lookup by username will be much faster - scanning for the list of usernames might be able to use an index-only scan (if the index exists).

Comment: I will recommend using a more informative title of the question

Answer (score 0):

If your WHERE clause compares by username (which is not indexed), it will probably do a full table scan. But, this may still be fast if the number of rows in the table is small. Computers are very fast these days and DBs are smart about organizing data for efficient table scans.

Comment: thanx...as you said, it scans all rows to match the where non-index condition, but if i have billions of records, and the username fields are not inserted alphabetically. Sequent scan can be time-cosuming, is there a way to get high preformance...? thanx

Comment: If you are going to compare on a column and you have many rows, consider adding an index.